# Cant access Magento session in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, session

I am making use of the Wordpress Plugin MWI - Mage/WP Integration to create a site that has Wordpress at its heart and Magento in a sub-folder.

I want to be able to access the Magento session in Wordpress pages. Thanks to the MWI plugin I am able to access a "customer/session", however it appears to be a different session to the one that is used when I go to the Magento part of the website.

I know this because I have added data to the session in Magento, but when I come to the homepage (powered by Wordpress) that custom data is not there!

Here is how Im adding the extra data in Magento:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData("foo","bar");
```

Then getting it with:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData("foo");
```

This returns NULL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after a little more trial & error I was able to resolve this.

Essentially, by switching to core/session rather than customer/session, I can then access the same session in Wordpress. So setting & getting become:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData("foo","bar");
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData("foo");
```

In Wordpress it is important to use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->getData("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin which does exactly that:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/mage-enabler/

Answer (score 0):

Also, as alternative solution, we can create simple module with the helper for getting session variables. Here's helper funtcion that returns Magento session:

```
    class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
    {
        public function getSession()
        {
            return return Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
        }
    }
```

Then we can access session data via such code:

```
    require_once('path_to/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();
    var_dump(Mage::helper('namespace_modulename')->getSession()->getData());
```